# Is it possible to display different reports with a single a report viewer?

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

Is it possible to display different with a single a report viewer such that when I click on the button "Report 1" to should display Report 1 in the Report Viewer.

If I click on the button "Report 2" it should display Report 2.

Is this possible ? If yes then please provide the code.

**EDIT 1 :**

I tried it like this, its not working

```
    frmReport.ReportViewer1.Reset()
    frmReport.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "sdvsdf.Report1.rdlc"
    frmReport.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: Looks like a good tutorial http://infinitenforever.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/vs-08-tip-multiple-reports-with-1-reportviewer/. But Can't figure out how to create a BindingSource :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the source of the report using the ServerReport or LocalReport properties on the ReportViewer object, depending on whether you're sourcing your reports from a SSRS server or are using local .rdlc files.

Comment: @Failed_Noob:  There's an example here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport(v=vs.80).aspx, that sets up a LocalReport object - you can use this object on your ReportViewer.

Comment: SO I need a LocalReport object to display each report. Any other simple method

Comment: @Failed_Noob - I don't think you can get anything simpler than this, it's quite straightforward.

Answer (score -3):

like this

printviewer1 = report1 ,vbnewline, Report2
then, turn off your computer and better get other course

Comment: if you are suggesting a couple lines of code why not include them as you think they should be written? Additionally, the answer isnt just about what to do but also why it works so that other reading the question might be able to use the concept to answer their own related but seperate questions.